# (Grails) GSP with semanticui

Tags: html, grails, gsp, semantic-ui

So this is how my folder looks like

[image]

I have two files one is gsp one is html and this is the exact same code for both

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="semantic/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    haluaw
    <button class="ui primary button">
  Save
</button>
<button class="ui button">
  Discard
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this is how gsp looks like

[image]

and this is how it looks like in html

[image]

Why does it not work in gsp while it works in html.. Its same folder and same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of path to CSS is wrong for gsp. The html files looks for the folder structure, and it finds the CSS file. But, Grails applications looks for css files on server URL.

You should be placing the CSS and js files in webapp folder in grails application and provide correct url path.

Comment: Thanks! didn't knew it has to be placed in a certain folder